# Populate form from child object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried searching for a solution on this but was not able to find the exact one.

Here is the scenario.

I have a list of objects `ctrl.Parents` and the parent object contains a list of childs just like we have a poco entity.

What I want is, to populate a select drop down from the child object. Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Sjz4JhYKq6uoJYsKrhRJ?p=preview) which is not complete, and following is the code that would give you an idea.

```js
// Code goes here
var app = angular.module("testApp", []);

app.controller("testCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.Parents = [{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "First Note",
    "TypeName": "First Type",
    "Notes": [{
      "Id": 1,
      "ParentID": 1,
      "Draft": "Draft 1",
      "Note": "First Draft"
    }, {
      "Id": 2,
      "ParentID": 1,
      "Draft": "Draft 2",
      "Note": "Second Draft"
    }]
  }, {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Second Note",
    "TypeName": "Second Type",
    "Notes": [{
      "Id": 3,
      "ParentID": 2,
      "Draft": "Draft 1",
      "Note": "First Draft"
    }, {
      "Id": 4,
      "ParentID": 2,
      "Draft": "Draft 4",
      "Note": "Second Draft"
    }]
  }]
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testApp">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <select ng-model="parent.name" ng-options="p.Name for p in Parents">
  </select>
  <br/>
  <b><span>Following list should be populated with Parent.Notes.Name
  as show in the <br/>
    EX: If Parent drop down has value First Note then following list will show</span></b>
  <br/>
  <select>
    <option selected="selected" value="Draft 1">Draft 1</option>
    <option value="Draft 2">Draft 2</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <span>And text will be as follows</span>
  <br/>
  <textarea>First Draft</textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at your plunker, It was almost right. You were trying to bind to properties that did not exists on the Notes model. Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testApp">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.1" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.1/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <select ng-model="parent" ng-options="p.Name for p in Parents">
  </select>
  <select ng-options="n.Note for n in parent.Notes" ng-model="Notes">

  </select>
</body>

</html>
```

If you want to select a default value add that to your model:

```
...//the end of your model
 }, {
      "Id": 4,
      "ParentID": 2,
      "Note": "Second Draft"
    }]
  }]
    $scope.parent = $scope.Parents[0];
});
```

In order to select a default child based on a value of a property you will have to update your code accordingly:

change your script.js to:

```
// Code goes here
var app = angular.module("testApp", []);

app.controller("testCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.Parents = [{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "First Note",
    "TypeName": "First Type",
    "Notes": [{
      "Id": 1,
      "ParentID": 1,
      "Note": "First Draft",
      "Def" : true
    }, {
      "Id": 2,
      "ParentID": 1,
      "Note": "Second Draft",
      "Def" : false
    }]
  }, {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Second Note",
    "TypeName": "Second Type",
    "Notes" : [{
      "Id": 3,
      "ParentID": 2,
      "Note": "First Draft",
      "Def" : false
    }, {
      "Id": 4,
      "ParentID": 2,
      "Note": "Second Draft",
      "Def" : true
    }]
  }];

  $scope.update = function() {
   $scope.Notes = $scope.findNote($scope.parent.Notes);
  }

   $scope.findNote = function (notes) {
        for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
            if (notes[i].Def == true) {
                return notes[i];
            }
        }
      }

});
```

and update your html:

```
<body ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <select ng-model="parent" ng-options="p.Name for p in Parents" ng-change="update()">
  </select>
  <select ng-options="n.Note for n in parent.Notes" ng-model="Notes" >

  </select>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the problem. I am really a newbie in this angular stuff. Can you tell me how to get a default selected value in this? Suppose I have a property named Default. It will be true for one and false for others. How will i set the default selected value?
And now I am confused which one should I mark as an answer cause both the answers worked :(

Comment: @Nilesh I have updated the answer to include the default selection. With regards to your question... I'll say the older answer :)

Comment: The older would be @huan :). What I want is, to select the default based on a boolean property which  I would send from the server. How would I achieve that? ex: If I have a proeprty IsSelected in one child object I want that particular value to be selected.

Comment: @Nilesh Sorry it took me so long to reply, but I was in a meeting. Hopefully that's what you needed.

Comment: I am still stuck. I am not getting any example which shows how to set the selected value in my HTML not in my controller. Can you help?

Comment: I don't think you can do it, at least I don't know how. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Is this help?

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DUGlQPkshMWOS7SFzPDf?p=preview)

```
<body ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <select ng-model="p" ng-options="p.Name for p in Parents">


  </select>


  <select ng-model="note.SelectedID" ng-options="note.Id for note in p.Notes">

  </select>

</body>
```

Comment: That was helpful. If I submit the form will the values bind back again to my model which I would send to the server?